# Letter Frequency - Python

Tags: python

I have the following set of instructions:

Create a variable to store the given string "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
Convert the given string to lowercase
Create a list containing every lowercase letter of the English alphabet

for every letter in the alphabet list: 
Create a variable to store the frequency of each letter in the string and assign it an initial value of zero 
for every letter in the given string:
if the letter in the string is the same as the letter in the alphabet list
increase the value of the frequency variable by one.
**if the value of the frequency variable does not equal zero:**
**print the letter in the alphabet list followed by a colon and the value of the frequency variable**

I am currently stuck in the **Bold** points.
So far, my code looks as follows:

```
import string
sentence = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
sentence = sentence. Lower()
alphabet_string = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet = list(alphabet_string)

for i in alphabet:
  frequency = {i: 0}
  for i in sentence:
    if i in frequency. Keys():
      frequency[i] = frequency[i] + 1
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the syntax errors yet?

Comment: You need a better set of instructions. Your current ones are leading you to write incorrect code. (btw a more pythonic way could be to use `collections.Counter` like this: `Counter((cr for cr in sentence if cr in alphabet))`)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is an extra condition statement for key - value pairs that have non zero values:

```
import string
sentence = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
sentence = sentence.lower()
alphabet_string = string.ascii_lowercase
alphabet = list(alphabet_string)

for i in alphabet:
  frequency = {i: 0}
  for j in sentence:
    if j in frequency.keys():
      frequency[i] = frequency[i] + 1
  if frequency[i] != 0:
    print(i, ',', frequency[i])
```

Outputs:

```
a , 10
b , 1
c , 2
d , 2
e , 2
f , 2
h , 4
i , 6
m , 2
n , 7
o , 9
r , 2
t , 10
u , 5
v , 2
w , 2
y , 2
```

Comment: thanks for this, I was exactly looking for this.
As I needed to use for loops.
I cannot rate your answer because I do not have the level just yet.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, *collections.Counter* is ideal for this.

However, your specification states that you're only interested in lowercase letters and the sentence contains ',', '.' and ' '

So there are two approaches... Use the traditional Counter then ignore values returned that don't fit with your rules. The other option is to write a custom class that handles those rules internally such that the output will only reveal lowercase ASCII letters having ignored irrelevant characters.

So, here's an idea:

```
class MyCounter:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = iterable
        self._result = None
    def items(self):
        if self._result is None:
            self._result = {}
            _alphabet = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
            for v in self._iterable:
                if v in _alphabet:
                    self._result[v] = self._result.get(v, 0) + 1
        return self._result.items()

sentence = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."

for k, v in MyCounter(sentence.lower()).items():
    print(f'{k}:{v}')
```

**Output:**

```
y:2
o:9
u:5
c:2
a:10
n:7
h:4
v:2
e:2
d:2
t:10
w:2
i:6
f:2
r:2
m:2
b:1
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as adding `if frequency[i] != 0: print(f'{i}: {frequency[i]}')`

Since `!= 0` consider as truthy condition, you can write like this:

```
import string
sentence = "You can have data without information, but you cannot have information without data."
sentence = sentence.lower()
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

for i in alphabet:
    frequency = {i: 0}
    for j in sentence:
        if j in frequency: frequency[i] += 1
    if frequency[i]: print(f'{i}: {frequency[i]}')
```

You can also change `frequency.keys()` to `frequency` and change `frequency[i] = frequency[i] + 1` to `frequency[i] += 1`